# Storm : java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: java, apache-storm

While submitting storm topology to cluster I am getting this error.

```
6653 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id 8ee90770-957a-40c7-a70b-fd7399cab6a1 at host Ritesh-RM
6706 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Jar not uploaded to master yet. Submitting jar...
6711 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Uploading topology jar /home/ubuntu/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/StormConsumer.jar to assigned location: /home/ubuntu/apache-storm-0.9.4/data/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-bb9e4775-748b-45ff-a91a-c170c65861e9.jar
6722 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: /home/ubuntu/apache-storm-0.9.4/data/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-bb9e4775-748b-45ff-a91a-c170c65861e9.jar
6722 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Submitting topology topology1 in distributed mode with conf {"nimbus.host":"localhost","cassandraKeyspaceName":"topology1","topology.workers":20,"nimbus.thrift.port":6627,"topology.max.spout.pending":500,"ignoreIPList":"iplist"}
6729 [main] ERROR org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.writeString(TBinaryProtocol.java:185) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.generated.StormTopology.write(StormTopology.java:588) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$submitTopology_args.write(Nimbus.java:2080) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:63) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.send_submitTopology(Nimbus.java:156) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.submitTopology(Nimbus.java:145) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:127) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:70) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
TopologyStructure.main(TopologyStructure.java:817) ~[StormConsumer.jar:na]
```

Comment: What did you change? Show us your code.

Comment: There are lot of changes in the code.Basically, I have added many new Bolts.The project is huge. I am unable to post the code.Can you tell me what could be the possible reasons?

Comment: PLease, check the updated error tree.

Comment: just wondering what is the value of `nimbus.host` in your code

Comment: There was some problem in the way I have linked my bolts.After debugging it thoroughly i corrected it.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: @Mike - One of my bolt was linked incorrectly which was causing the problem.Also , this a generic error.Many misconfiguration throw this error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason you were getting a `NullPointerException` was due to a missing bolt Id.

It could be when you are using the `TopologyBuilder` to `setBolt` you are passing a `null` as the `id`?